# Local Spark config

Tags: python, apache-spark, pyspark, apache-spark-sql

I have created a local spark environment in docker. I intend to use this as part of a CICD pipeline for unit testing code executed in the spark environment. I have two scripts which I want to use: 1 will create a set of persistent spark databases and tables and the other will read those tables. Even though the tables should be persistent, they only persist in that specific spark session. If I create a new spark session, I cannot access the tables, even though it is visible in the file system. Code examples are below:

## Create db and table

Create_script.py

```
from pyspark.sql import SparkSession
def main():
    spark = SparkSession.builder.appName('Example').getOrCreate()
    columns = ["language", "users_count"]
    data = [("Java", "20000"), ("Python", "100000"), ("Scala", "3000")]
    rdd = spark.sparkContext.parallelize(data)
    df = rdd.toDF(columns)
    spark.sql("create database if not exists schema1")
    df.write.mode("ignore").saveAsTable('schema1.table1')
```

## Load Data

load_data.py

```
from pyspark.sql import SparkSession
spark = SparkSession.builder.appName('example').getOrCreate()
df = spark.sql("select * from schema1.table1")
```

I know there is a problem as when I run this command: print(spark.catalog.listDatabases()) It can only find database default. But if I import Create_script.py then it will find schema1 db.

How do I make persistent tables across all spark sessions?

[image: ls from filesystem]

Comment: Can you create an internal Hive table and use it across programs?

Comment: I haven't configured Hive yet so not easily.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

These files in `/repo/test/spark-warehouse` is only data of the tables, without meta info of database/table/column.

If you don't enable Hive, Spark use an `InMemoryCatalog`, which is ephemeral and only for testing, only available in same spark context. This `InMemoryCatalog` doesn't provide any function to load db/table from file system.

So there is two way:

1. **Columnar Format**

   - `spark.write.orc()`, write data into orc/parquet format in your `Create_script.py` script.  orc/parquet format store column info aside with data.
   - `val df = spark.read.orc()`,  then `createOrReplaceTempView` if you need use it in sql.
2. **Use Embed Hive**

   You don't need to install Hive, Spark can work with embed hive, just two steps.

   - add spark-hive dependency. (I'm using Java which use pom.xml to manage dependencies, I don't know how to do it in pyspark)
   - `SparkSession.builder().enableHiveSupport()`

   Then data will be `/repo/test/spark-warehouse/schema1.db`, meta info will be `/repo/test/metastore_db`, which contains files of Derby db. You can read or write tables across all spark sessions.

Comment: Thanks for the explanation. This makes total sense and I have been able to get option 2 working.